# .Net DrawLine in OnPaint(), line is behind the control in panel

Tags: c#, vb.net

In the picture ([Picture Click Me](http://i35.photobucket.com/albums/d180/a15752468/JustPic_zps4da80f77.png)),

- The blue rectangle is the control with backcolor = Transparent ( user control inherits by System.Windows.Form.Control )
- i draw the blue line on "Transparent Control"
- "Transparent Control's Z-Order is Top"
- In the picture, Left: Textbox and Transparent Control has no problem.
- In the picture, Right: Panel(gray), Textbox is in Panel control, and TransparentControl is just lay over on it, but part of blue line will show behind the Textbox.

Question is:
  The Textbox is behind "Transparent Control", but why blue line will cut by Textbox.
  And this case only when Textbox in the Panel.

How to fix this bug.

Transparent Control's code is below

```
Public Class TransparentPanel
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control


  ' To Set Transparent backcolor, Overrides CreateParams And OnPaintBackground.
  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
      Dim cp As Windows.Forms.CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
      cp.ExStyle &= &H20
      Return cp
    End Get
  End Property

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    'MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
  End Sub



  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    ' Draw blue line and Rectabgle
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2), 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2), 2, 2, Me.Width - 4, Me.Height - 4)

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Try to put ii not __into__ the Panel. Move it out with the Mouse and then move it back with the __keyboard__! This is not so much about z-order but about parenthood. if you move a control over a container the container will become the control's parent. this won't happen when you use the keyboard. or you can set the parent in code..

Comment: Using WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is filled with traps.  Your nemesis is certainly TextBox, a control that dates from the 1980s and breaks the rules.  Necessary back then to perform acceptably on a 386SUX processor.  It colors outside of the lines by painting itself directly instead of using the normal paint cycle. Ruining your transparency by overdrawing the blue line.  You can only make this work consistently by overlaying another top-level window, a Form that uses the TransparencyKey property.  Or switch to WPF, it doesn't use windows to implement controls.

Comment: i'm sure the parent of TextBox is Panel, and Transparent Control's parent is Form. if put Transparent Control into Panel (TextBox and Transparent Control is same parent), the blue line will draw currect.